# DLL use in Python 2.7 with ctypes

Tags: python, parameters, ctypes

I have a problem about using DLL file. The code I used is below. In handbook of DLL it writes the signiture of function. I'm using Python 2.7

```
from ctypes import *
mtrs= windll.LoadLibrary("mtrs.dll")
mtrs.sw_Open("SystemWorks", 0, c_ulong( 0x100 | 0x10000), None, None)
0
```

In handbook of DLL it writes the signature of function.

```
DLLINOUT BOOL WINAPI sw_Open(LPCSTR DeviceName, ULONG DeviceNumber, ULONG OpenFlags, void * Arg1, void * Arg2 );
```

Function returns false if device is not opened.

Is there any error in parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3x, you should use `b"SystemWorks"` because first argument has `LPCSTR` type.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from ctypes import *
mtrs= windll.LoadLibrary("mtrs.dll")
mtrs.sw_Open.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_ulong, c_ulong, c_void_p, c_void_p]
mtrs.sw_Open.restype = c_bool
mtrs.sw_Open(b"SystemWorks", c_ulong(0), c_ulong( 0x100 | 0x10000), None, None)
```

Comment: why `c_ulong(0)` and not just `0`?

Comment: @Abyx. `implicit conversion` happened if not.

Comment: so why do you use explicit creating of `c_ulong`?

Comment: @Abyx. It's just my personal coding style. Not a big deal.